# CiviContribution: Modify contribution fail

Tags: civicontribute

We have a problem that seems to have been there forever with our civiCRM. Indeed, once a contribution from a donor is recorded, it is not possible to modify it afterwards with the "modify" option on the contribution's page. Instead, an error saying that "Contributor is a required field" appears, although the contributor field is filled and cannot be changed. As a result we have to delete the contribution and create a new one every time we need to change something. I have attached a screen shot in French.

If anyone has an idea on how that could be sorted that would be fantastic.

Gaëtan[image]

Comment: What version are you using? Do you have any extensions installed relating to contributions?

Comment: The version of the CiviCRM is the 5.59.3 and here is a list of all the extensions that we have, as I am not sure which one could be related to extensions:
Angular Profiles : Version 4.7.31-1.1.2
AuthX : Version 5.59.3
Bootstrap layout for civisualize : Version 1.0
CiviCRM Export to Excel : Version 2.4
Civisualize. The missing data visualization extension : Version 6.1
CKEditor4 : Version 5.59.3
Contribution cancel actions : Version 5.59.3
Custom search framework : Version 5.59.3
Event Cart : Version 5.59.3
ExtendedReport : Version 5.21
Financial ACLs : Version 5.59.3

Comment: FlexMailer : Version 5.59.3
FormBuilder : Version 5.59.3
Form Core : Version 5.59.3
iATS Payments : Version 1.7.5
Localization Update : Version 1.0-beta
Mailchimp : Version 2.0.1
No Drill Down : Version 1.1.5
reCAPTCHA : Version 5.59.3
SearchKit : Version 5.59.3
Sequential credit notes : Version 5.59.3
Summary Fields : Version 5.0.2
Theme: Greenwich : Version 5.59.3

Answer (score 0):

After rechecking administrator permissions and clearing the cache, the problem is now resolved. Successive updates to the CIVI core have certainly added new rules that had not been properly revised.